# Wildcard match is very comprehensive, but can not find the element 'mvc: default-servlet-handler' statement)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am learning Spring MVC now and i run a demo as the guide on the Internet, but the bug is

> [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 35; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: 通配符的匹配很全面, 但无法找到元素 'mvc:default-servlet-handler' 的声明(Wildcard match is very comprehensive, but can not find the element 'mvc: default-servlet-handler' statement)**.

Here is my mvc-dispatch-servlet.xml file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <!--指明 controller 所在包，并扫描其中的注解-->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.snow.controller"/>
    <!-- 静态资源(js、image等)的访问 -->
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    <!-- 开启注解 -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!--ViewResolver 视图解析器-->
    <!--用于支持Servlet、JSP视图解析-->
    <bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
```

And i have changed pom.xml  the spring version from 4.3.5 to 4.3.6, but it's no use.
would you help to check why ?

Comment: How about you just remove the XML comments?

Comment: I try just now, it's no use.

Comment: Well, the error should be different when you remove them, so please update the question.

Comment: the error is the same and i found the bug, it's the element xsi:schemaLocation statment error. it should add http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd.

Answer (score 0):

the same question,I fix it.
https://github.com/gaussic/SpringMVCDemo/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

replace the code from github url new.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">
```